# a countable dense subset of Lipschitz functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, approximation-theory

Suppose $(X,d)$ is a metric space and let $\mathcal{L}$ be the space of *bounded* Lipschitz functions on $X$. Let $D$ be a countable dense subset of $X$ and consider the set of functions $$h_{q_1,q_2,k,y}(x)=\min\{(q_1+q_2d(x,y)),k\}, \ q_1, q_2, k \in \mathbb{Q}, \ q_2,k\in(0,1), \ y \in D$$ and let $\mathcal{D}$ the set generated by these functions by taking $\inf$ over finitely many of them. Let $\mathcal{C}=\{\lambda f\ | \ \lambda\in\mathbb{Q}, f\in \mathcal{D}\}$. Is it true that $\mathcal{C}$ is dense (with the uniform metric) in $\mathcal{L}$? If so, how can I prove it? Hints or references are also greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE** copper.hat pointed out this is false when $X=\mathbb{R}$. Is it true if $(X,d)$ is compact?

(Reference: page 107 of this book: http://www.springer.com/birkhauser/mathematics/book/978-3-7643-8721-1 )

Comment: This set is not dense, since by definition $h(x) \le 1$ for all $x \in X, \, h \in \mathcal{D}$.

Comment: I agree, this doesn't look like it's true. Maybe finite linear combinations of these functions $h$ are dense?

Comment: @copper.hat I've edited the question, thanks.

Comment: @copper.hat I've rephrased the question. I don't know if it's true.

Comment: perhaps it's too late, but [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2651978/is-banach-space-of-lipschitz-function-separable) answer shows that Lipschitz spaces are not separable (in the Lipschitz norm), hence you cannot have a countable dense subset

Answer (score 2):

Let $X=\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric.

First take a representative $h(x) = \min(a+b|x-y|, c)$, where $b \ge 0$. If $b=0$, then $h$ is a constant, if $b \neq 0$ then for $|x|$ sufficiently large we see that $h$ is constant.

We then see that if $d \in {\cal D}$ then for $|x|$ sufficiently large, $d$ is a eventually a constant.

Hence, if $h \in {\cal C}$, then it is eventually a constant.

Choose $f(x) = \min_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} |x-2k|$. Note that $f(2n) = 0, f(2n+1) = 1$ for all integers $n$.

Suppose $h \in {\cal C}$ such that $\|f-h\|_\infty < {1 \over 4}$, in particular
$h$ is eventually a constant, which gives a contradiction.

Comment: Isn't $q_1\leq h_{q_1,q_2,k,y}(x)\leq k< 1 \ \forall x $ by definition, implying the functions in $\mathcal{D}$ are bounded?

Comment: If $q_2 <0$ then no.

Comment: I may have mistread the question, is $q_2 \in \mathbb{Q}$ or $g_2 \in (0,1)$?

Comment: $q_2$ is a rational number between 0 and 1.

Comment: I see that now, I think it would have been a little clearer to write $q_2 \in (0,1) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ :-).

Comment: The answer was still valid, I just removed the irrelevant parts.

Comment: That's very good, thanks. Do you reckon it'd be true if $X$ were compact?