# Is Banach Space of Lipschitz Function Separable?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, lipschitz-functions

To simplify the question, let $X=[0,1]$ with Euclidean distance. Denote $$L_f=\sup_{x,y\in X}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|},$$
and
$$||f||_L=\max\{L_f,||f||_\infty\}.$$
Consider space $$Lip_0(X)=\{f: f(0)=0,||f||_L<\infty\}.$$
On $Lip_0(X)$, $||.||_L$ is equivalent to $L_f$, because $X$ is bounded.
There are some famous results about this space, for example $Lip_0(X)$ is complete w.r.t. $||.||_L$ and separable w.r.t. $||.||_\infty$. I was wondering if $Lip_0(X)$ is separable under the norm $||.||_L$. And if not, what kind of conditions or modifications are needed to make it separable. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Oops,** I lied. I said

"Certainly it's separable. For example, convolution with the Cesaro kernel shows that trigonometric polynomials are dense; hence trigonometric polynomials with rational coefficients are dense."

and that seemed right, but it was a little glib. The space $Lip_1$ is essentially an $L^\infty$ sort of thing, and convolving an $L^\infty$ funtion with an approximate identity does *not* give convergence in the $L^\infty$ norm. And of course $L^\infty$ is not separable...

No, actually $Lip_0$ is not separable. For $0<h<1$ define $f_h$ by $$f_h(0)=0,\quad f_h'=\chi_{(0,h)}.$$

Then $||f_h-f_{h'}||_{L}\ge1$ for $h\ne h'$. This is clear for various reasons;  some readers may just consider the supremum of the derivative, other readers may prefer to just draw a picture.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I am a Stats student and no longer that familiar with functional analysis. Would you mind giving some more details about the convolution staff?

Comment: @JinqiShen I lied. See correction...

Comment: Thank for your help, although I really hope this space is separable for my research. :)

Comment: It is very likely that the Lipschitz space is separable in the weak-* topology if the underlying space is compact. I haven't checked it, but the above example with the Cesaro kernel should give a countable weakly-* dense system. There are other options, of course